# LaTeX type rendering with pygame

Tags: python, latex, pygame

I am trying to read text with LaTeX formatting and render it using pygame. I am a novice to pygame and any help will be appreciated.

I looked into Glyph package. The problem is that I would have to rewrite all my .txt files in Glyph formatting for them to be useful. If I try and define macros I would essentially have to build a LaTeX translator. Both these options don't seem very practical considering the number of text files I have.

Answer (score 1):

You could render LaTeX via matplotlib and use these figures in PyGame as sprites.

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/usetex.html

Answer (score 1):

Check out [pylasem](https://github.com/jbaayen/pylasem/) (yes, it says MathML rendering library, but it also supports a subset of Latex) or [lasem](http://live.gnome.org/Lasem) itself via gobject-introspection.